# Getting current stroke color programmatically

Tags: android

I am able to set my shape's stroke color by doing this:

```
GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) myview.getBackground();
shape.setStroke(strokeWidth, color);
```

**Q:** How do I **get** the current color of my shape's **stroke** programmatically?

Note that I am using API level 19 (so I cannot use shape.getColor() which anyway would return the filling color of the shape I believe, and not it's stroke's color).

Comment: if you take a look into the [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java) you will see it is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pskink mentioned, Checking android [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java) shows that there is no such API for getting the current stroke color (which is odd and a pity).

Eventually what I did to overcome my problem, is keeping my own variable in code that indicates the current stroke color.